# $x(t)\rightarrow x(-t)$ and $x(t)\rightarrow x^\ast(-t)$ transforms

Tags: linear-transformations, signal-processing

I have to determine if these transforms are linear and the core of the transforms:

- $x(t)\rightarrow x(-t), \quad  t\in \mathbb{R}$
- $x(t)\rightarrow x^\ast(-t), \quad  t\in \mathbb{R}$

With "the core of the transforms" I mean the filter function $h(t)$ that performs the transform if I convolve it with $x(t)$

Comment: Do you know what the Dirac delta is?

Comment: Yes, I had thought that delta can help me but if h(t)=delta then I get back x(t).

Comment: The solution should be exists because I found this question in a signal processing test.

Comment: Here's an idea: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)\delta(t+\tau)\,d\tau = x(-t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)h(t-\tau)\,d\tau.$$ From there, see if you can reverse engineer what $h$ has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Denote the Fourier transform by $\mathscr{F}$, you may show
 $$ \mathscr{F}^2 ( x(t)) = x(-t), \quad t \in \mathbb{R} $$
when it is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I express the $\mathscr{F}^2 $ as core of the transform?